# What is $l$-th division polynomial of $E$?

Tags: field-theory, terminology, definition, elliptic-curves

I am reading some papers about elliptic curves and I come across the term $l$-th division polynomial of $E$. I don't really know much about field theory and I tried to look for this definition but I'm unable to find it. 
I'm wondering if anyone can provide a high level explanation?

Sorry if this question is too basic.

Comment: They are defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials

Answer (score 1):

If one has an elliptic curve $E$ in Weierstrass form
$$y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$
and take a typical point $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and consider the multiples of it
in the elliptic curve group
$[n]P=P+\cdots+P=(x_n,y_n)$ then
$$x_n=\frac{\phi_n(x_1)}{\psi_n(x_1)^2}$$
where $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ are polynomials. Then the $\psi_n(x)$ are the
*division polynomials*: $[n]P=O$ iff $\psi_n(x_1)=0$.

This isn't strictly true. When $n$ is odd this works fine. When $n$ is
even $\psi_n(x_1)$ isn't really a polynomial in $x_1$, it actually
equals $y_1$ times a polynomial in $x_1$, but as $y_1^2=x_1^3+\cdots$
then $\psi_n(x_1)^2$ is a polynomial in $x_1$.

There's a good account of all this in Washington's book on elliptic curves.

Comment: hi! thank you very much for your detailed answer. So just to clarify, p_n is the the n-th division polynomial

Comment: also I'm wondering is the normal definition that 4 of them are defined to begin with as the base cases, and then the m-th poylnomial or the mth + 1 polynomial are then defined recursively based off of those 4?